# Bind javadoc and sources goals to deploy phase before deploy goal is run

Tags: java, maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I would like my project to generate javadoc and sources artifacts only when I activate the `deploy` phase, not when I ask for `mvn install`. That is because I only need those artifacts when deploying, and I want to save time when not deploying.

Therefore, I thought about binding the `maven-source-plugin` goal to the `deploy` phase.

But, I need those artifacts to exist at the time the `deploy` goal runs. Thus, the source and javadoc generation goals must run before the deploy goal. Unfortunately, the goal from the packaging is executed first (as [documented](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Plugins)).

I am aware the usual [advice](https://github.com/oliviercailloux/java-course/blob/master/Maven/Maven%20central.adoc#conditional-deployments) is to define a “release” profile and define the javadoc plugin (and related ones) only there. But this seems needlessly complicated for my simple use case. Now I need to think about activating the release profile exactly when I ask for deploying, I would prefer the right plugins to be activated automatically depending on the phase I ask for.

I am surprised this does not seem to be considered possible or even desirable by Maven (as it does not seem to allow for a goal to run in the deploy phase but before the deploy goal). Did I miss something, is this possible? Or, is there any reason not to do it in the way I consider? (Otherwise, I am thinking about introducing a feature request.)

Comment: in this case I seems the advice to use a profile fits best. The javadoc files you create would actually also be used for the install phase when the artifacts are copied into the local repository. You might be able to gain control over this by configuring the source plugin to the deploy phase and also the deploy plugin itself (mainly keeping the defaults, only put it below in the pom). Since the order in the pom will be reflected in the execution order.

Comment: “The javadoc files you create would actually also be used for the install phase when the artifacts are copied into the local repository.” ⇒ Very good point, thank you.